# JdbcTemplate is null in Springboot application using Oracle 10g

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot

Using spring-boot 2.7.2
Error -
*java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(String, org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper)" because "this.jdbcTemplate" is null*

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
.....
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

}

@Component
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
    
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public UserDaoImpl(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplatn) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
    
    @Override
    public  List<AttributeData> getAttributes() {
        String query = "select attributeid, ....";
        List<AttributeData> attributes = jdbcTemplate.query(query, new AttributeMapper());
        return attributes;
    }
}

application.properties :
# Oracle db related
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost....
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

# JPA related
oracle.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Answer (score 0):

Just means that you don't have a `@Bean` defining the JdbcTemplate, e.g.

```
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() throws SQLException {
    final JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate();
    template.setDataSource(dataSource());
    template.afterPropertiesSet();
    return template;
}
```

Comment: Because I am using spring-data-jpa, Spring Boot automatically creates a JdbcTemplate. The @Autowired JdbcTemplate field automatically loads it and makes it available. Removed the constructor and made the field jdbcTemplate autowired...this solved the problem. 
Now the question is : why field injection worked and not constructor injection?